# Pointer Ownership in the Win32 API

Tags: c++, c, windows, pointers, winapi

I'm trying to understand how the Win32 API handles Pointer ownership.

The concrete example i am looking at right now is the ownership of pointers to strings that i pass to the API and that i get from the API.

Take for example the `SetWindowText` function. It takes an `LPCSTR`, a pointer to a null terminated widestring.

Another example would be the `RegisterClass` function and in conjunction the `WNDCLASS` struct.
The `RegisterClass` function takes a pointer to a `WNDCLASS` struct and the `WNDCLASS` struct again contains a `LPCSTR` to the class name.

Does the API take ownership of that memory or do i need to handle freeing it?

It seems unlikely to me that it would take ownership but my knowledge of C/C++ conventions isn't good enough to say for certain, and i cant find any documentation about ownership conventions for the API.

Comment: The Windows "Win32" API doesn't care much about C or C++ conventions, or that of other programming languages. This is really a good thing, if you look at Linux where the two are tangled up causing unfortunate dependencies. `malloc` is C; `HeapAlloc` is Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer is: Read the documentation for the function in question. If it doesn't say anything about taking ownership, then it's a good bet that it doesn't take ownership and you need to deal with the memory.

Although it's been a while since I did much significant work at the level of the Windows API, I recall occasionally coming across functions that documented they required memory to be allocated via a particular method in first place - because that's the only way to know how to properly deallocate it.

And that leads to the second way to reason about this. Imagine you were the implementer of the function. If you were just given a raw pointer with no other information about it, could you know how the deallocate the memory it points to? Was that memory allocated with `new`? `malloc`? some other API call? or maybe it's on the stack? C / C++ / the level of the Windows API doesn't have any facility to determine how memory was allocated from just having a pointer alone. So most functions are just not going to deal with that hassle if they don't need to. And the few that have a good reason will have to follow the route of documenting their requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the API take ownership of that memory or do i need to handle freeing it?

There is no such automatic memory management in `Win32 API`. If you allocate some data in your program and give this data to `Win32 API` functions, you will have to `free` it in your program.

`API` in C are usually designed like that, because there is no way for the other layers to determine if the pointers are used somewhere else in the program. If manual memory management is annoying for you, you could search for `garbage collectors` which will manage the memory automatically for you, with a small tradeoff regarding performances.

Comment: GdiPlus complicates things somewhat. In some circumstances, it'll allocate some memory when loading image files, and unless I'm mistaken, _you'll_ need to manage its cleanup later. It's long been a source of leaks.

Comment: `API in C are usually designed like that, because there is no way for the other layers to determine if the pointers are used somewhere else in the program.`

Which is not universally true since a passing convention of "if you give me a pointer i own that memory now and will handle the cleanup, you better not be using it any more" is a way for the API to assume it has ownership of the Memory.

As i said, it's highly unlikely but i would rather not trip over such a footgun and as @enhzflep pointed out, exceptions to the rule happen.

Comment: This is correct, but I read a lot of C code and from my experience, the `allocation` functions are most of the time attached to a `free` function. So the layer which allocate the memory is also responsible to free it.

Comment: @ErikSchulze A pointer to some memory doesn't contain enough information to let anyone free it, and often may not be enough. There is as many ways to allocate memory as there are people you ask, and any disagreement = crash. So this doesn't work. APIs that need to clean up memory can either: 1. Provide that memory to begin with (via an allocation function exposed to the user), or 2. Ask for three pointers: a memory pointer, an opaque pointer, and a deallocator function pointer. The deallocator would be passed both former pointers and do the deallocation job.

Comment: C++ is garbage collected, it's just that [everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203). Regardless, things aren't this simple. There are interfaces in the Windows API that do transfer ownership ([FormatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage), for example, if requested). COM is another area where it's common to pass ownership around (e.g. [IEnumString::Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ienumstring-next)).